# How to check if a tuple contains an element in Apache Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

Let's say I have this file:

```
movie_id,title,genres
95004,Superman/Doomsday (2007),Action|Animation
136297,Mortal Kombat: The Journey Begins (1995),Action
193565,Gintama: The Movie (2010),Action|Animation|Comedy|Sci-Fi
193573,Love Live! The School Idol Movie (2015),Animation
```

I load it like this:

```
movies = LOAD 'movies.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (moviesId:int, title:chararray, genres: chararray);
movies = FOREACH movies GENERATE movieId, title, STRSPLIT(genres,'\\|') as genres;
describe a;       //a: {movieId: int,title: chararray,genres: ()}
```

Example of `dump a` results:

```
...
(193581,Black Butler: Book of the Atlantic (2017),(Action,Animation,Comedy,Fantasy))
(193583,No Game No Life: Zero (2017),(Animation,Comedy,Fantasy))
...
```

Now, if I undestand correctly, the field genres is of type tuple. The question is how can I do a query such as: "get all the action movies?". I don't know how to check if a specific element is present in the tuple genres.

I know how to do this with a Python UDF function, but I would like to know if it is possible without one. Maybe I should load the file differently.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to put the genres into a bag rather than into a tuple (I think this would be more appropriate since the number of genres varies from record to record). This could be then solved with a nested `FOREACH` by filtering the bag for specific genres then testing to see if the bag is not empty.

```
movies = LOAD 'movies.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (moviesId:int, title:chararray, genres: chararray);
moviesSplit = FOREACH movies GENERATE movieId, title, TOKENIZE(genres,'|') as genres;

actionTest = FOREACH moviesSplit {
    action = FILTER genres by $0 == 'Action';
    GENERATE *, action;

actionMovies = FILTER actionTest BY NOT IsEmpty(action);
```